# Pandas Pivot Creating NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Given this sample dataframe,

```
         Cents      Date
MN                                         
Shop        0.03  01012019
Shop        0.22  01012019
Shop        0.12  01012019
Shop        0.08  02012019
Shop        0.02  02012019
Shop        0.02  02012019
Shop        0.02  03012019
Shop        0.09  03012019
Shop        0.11  03012019
Shop        0.02  04012019
Shop        0.03  04012019
Shop        0.04  04012019
```

I will like to reshape my dataframe to become

[image]

What I have tried so far,

1. Drop the index of the original sample dataframe

   ```
   df1 = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   ```
2. Pivot the sample dataframe,

   ```
   df1.pivot(index=None, columns='Date', values='Cents')
   ```

I am unable to get the desired result I want after pivoting, this is what I get

[image]

Can someone advise me on why is this happening? I am pretty sure it has something to do with how the pivot works with my dataframe (maybe I need a unique index which I can't have in this case?). Will appreciate if you can let me know how I should continue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need a `groupby` + `cumcount` create an additional key

```
Yourdf= df.assign(key=df.groupby('Date').cumcount()).pivot(index='key',columns='Date',values='Cents')
Yourdf
Out[37]: 
Date  1012019  2012019  3012019  4012019
key                                     
0        0.03     0.08     0.02     0.02
1        0.22     0.02     0.09     0.03
2        0.12     0.02     0.11     0.04
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks! Out of knowledge, can you kindly explain on why I will need an additional key? Isn't the index='x' in my pivot code do the same? Your output result is slightly different from what I want - I will like to have a 'Cents' row inbetween the date and values, is this possible?

Comment: @SunnyBoiz the problem here is , your do not have common key between each date , that is why you have so many NaN with the original index